Grails 6.2 support is missing in intelliJ IDEA
I don't seem to have Grails support in intelliJ in my new project after installing the grails plugin.  By "support" I mean I:

Don't see the Grails menu item under tools
Can't right-click on grails-app/conrollers and see "New->Grails Controller"

I've tried:

Enabling/disabling the Grails plugin (numerous times)
Restarting intelliJ  (numerous times)
Explicitly adding my Grails library as an external library and adding it as a dependency in Modules.
I tried reinstalling everything on a clean Windows VM...same results
Asking ChatGPT
Cursing the Heavens

I have an old grails project that still has support.  It's just any new project I make.
Environment:

Windows Server 2022 running on EC2
IntelliJ 2024.1.4 Ultimate updated to current (241.18034.62)
Grails Plugin 241.14494.158
Grails 6.2


It's hard to know the exact problem, but check the answers in this issue to make sure you've added Grails Framework support to your project.
That's an extremely old question on an extremely old version of IntelliJ, but something similar should still be around.

The 6.2 Grails version is not always compatible with the latest IDE build. There is a number of similar reports in IntelliJ IDEA public bug tracker.
Workaround 1: downgrade Grails version from 6.2 to e.g., 6.1.2
Workaround 2: downgrade the IDE version to 2021.3. You can download it here

I fixed this by adding dependency in build.gradle. Then, Grails 6.2.0 worked for me in IntelliJ 2022 as well.
implementation("org.grails:grails-shell:6.1.2")

Bugs reported to JetBrains - Solution by James Fredley
